# Java: Read a txt file and save it in an array of strings but without backslashes (spaces)?

Tags: java, text

I am using this code to read a txt file, line by line.

```
// Open the file that is the first command line parameter 
FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("/Users/dimitramicha/Desktop/SweetHome3D1.txt");
// Get the object of DataInputStream
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
String strLine;
// Read File Line By Line
int i = 0;
while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
    str[i] = strLine;
    i++;
}
// Close the input stream
in.close();
```

and I save it in an array.

Afterwards, I would like to make an if statement about the Strings that I saved in the array. But when I do that it doesn't work, because (as I've thought) it saves also the spaces (backslashes). Do you have any idea how I can save the data in the array but without spaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do:

```
strLineWithoutSpaces = strLine.replace(' ', '');
str[i] = strLineWithoutSpaces;
```

You can also do more replaces if you find other characters that you don't want.

Comment: Well I tried  String strLineWithoutSpaces = strLine.replace(" ","");
     str[i] = strLineWithoutSpaces; but it is not right yet...

Comment: After looking into this more, I found this works: strLine.replaceAll("\\s+", "");  If you want more in depth deletion of white space (not always middle), check out this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2932392/java-how-to-replace-2-or-more-spaces-with-single-space-in-string-and-delete-leadi

Comment: Still, all the blanks are not gone... I also used replaceAll("^ +| +$|( )+", "$1") as the other post suggests.

Comment: What if I just want to replace \n ?

Comment: Try: strLine.replaceAll("\n", ""); ReplaceAll takes a Regex and you can read more about them: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [replace](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) method in `String` and call it on `strLine` before putting it in the array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Scanner](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) which by default uses white space to separate tokens. Have a look at [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/scanning.html) tutorial.