# Parse whitespaces from String value to HTTP url standard

Tags: android, string, parsing, removing-whitespace

How can I get a parse String of city name without whitespaces (on the start and at the end) and with "%20" instead of " " (which contains some city names) in android.

For example I would like to parse:

```
" Oklahoma " -> "Oklahoma"
```

or

```
"    Oklahoma    City" -> "Oklahoma%20City"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java how to replace 2 or more spaces with single space in string and delete leading spaces only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2932392/java-how-to-replace-2-or-more-spaces-with-single-space-in-string-and-delete-lead)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Uri.encode(" Oklahoma  City".trim())
```

Output :

Oklahoma%20%City

Comment: "Oklahoma [space][space]City" Output: `Oklahoma%20%20City` ... should be `" Oklahoma  City".replaceAll("\\s+", " ").trim()`

Comment: For me Leonid's code works fine. I get from geocode API what I need! But thanks you too.