# Java reduce whitespaces almost like a HTML renderer

Tags: java, regex

I've been trying around to get this working with regular expressions but I just keep failing, so maybe someone more experienced with this can help?

How can I render a string close to the way any webbrowser renders a html string? 
Example HTML:

```html
<html>
  Hel
lo 
  how
 are   you
</html>
```

Is rendered:

```
Hel lo how are you
```

I want it to be

```
Hello how are you
```

So the difference to html is that a newline without explicit spaces is just removed. In java this string would look like this:

```
\tHel\nlo \n  how\n are    you
```

My current solution:

```
// remove linebreaks and tabs and any leading or trailing whitespace
// this is necessary to avoid converting \t or \n to a space
script = script.replaceAll("\\s+\n\\s+", "");
script = script.replaceAll("\\s+\t\\s+", "");
// remove any length of whitespace and replace it with one
script = script.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
// rewmove leading and trailing whitespaces
script = script.trim();
```

Has only one problem: 
If I have a line with a trailing space followed by a newline and some more text, the trailing space will be removed:

```
Hello \nhow are you?
```

will be reduced to

```
Hellohow are you
```

So, using underscore (_) as space marker the following should be true:

```
_ = _
__ = _
\t\n_ = _
_\t\n = _
\t_\n = _
_\t_\n_ = _
\n = // nothing
\t = // nothing
\t\n = // nothing
```

What combination of replaceAll(regex, string) would I need to use?

Comment: You're looking for regex.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java how to replace 2 or more spaces with single space in string and delete leading spaces only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2932392/java-how-to-replace-2-or-more-spaces-with-single-space-in-string-and-delete-lead)

Comment: .replaceAll(" +"," ")

Comment: What have you tried so far and what's the problem. I suppose you figured out the obvious regex by yourself?!

Comment: I've completely reworked the question also including my current solution

Comment: How about `Hello\nhow are you?`. What should be the desired output after normalization?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think - given your current examples - you want to change your replace function to this:

```java
// remove any newlines or tabs (leading or trailing whitespace doesn't matter)
script = script.replaceAll("(\\\t|\\\n)", "");
// boil down remaining whitespace to a single space
script = script.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
script = script.trim();
```

This will of course cause something like

```
Hello\nhow are you?
```

to be reduced to

```
Hellohow are you?
```

But this is something that is an inherent consequence of your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

The regex `\s` matches all whitespace. Therefore I believe you just need `myString.trim().replaceAll("\\s+", " ");`

Comment: Won't that leave one leading space?

Comment: True, you could just do `myString.trim()` first.

Comment: I've already tried it that way. I've updated my question explaining why that is not enough. I need to explicitly differentiate between spaces and tabs / newlines

Comment: I'll have a look at a new solution tomorrow but in the mean time, can you tell me why you think trim will change `Hi \nthere` to `Hithere`? If it is the same string, that space in between is not considered trailing...

Comment: Sorry, updated the comment. Of course it's not "trimmed" but my current regex replacements are reducing it in an unwanted way.