# How to replace a string without leaving empty space in between?

Tags: java, regex, replace

I tried removing a particular word from a string, I end up getting an extra space in between other words. This is the code i used

```
String title = "Senior Account Manager Presidio Networke";
title = title.replace("Presidio","");
```

Output: Senior Account Manager " " Networke ,

I get an extra white space in between manager and networke

Comment: The original problem can be also solved using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2932392/java-how-to-replace-2-or-more-spaces-with-single-space-in-string-and-delete-lead).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Capture all possible preceding and following whitespace, and then replace with a single space:

```
title = title.replaceAll("\\s+Presidio\\s+", " ").trim();
```

Note: The call to `String#trim` handles the edge cases where `Presidio` might appear as either the first or last word in the sentence.  In this case, we don't even want a single space in the replacement, we want empty string.

Comment: The only trouble with `trim()` here is when the string starts/ends with whitespace that should be kept after the replacement.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew You're right...my solution would remove this whitespace regardless, and that may not be desired.

Answer (score 2):

Do like this

```
title = title.replace(" Presidio","");
```

Comment: What if a sentence starts with that word?

Answer (score 0):

```
private String removeWord(String unwanted, String sentence)
{
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(sentence);
    String remainder = "";

    while(st.hasMoreTokens())
    {
        String temp = st.nextToken();

        if(!temp.equals(unwanted))
        {
            remainder += temp + " ";
        }
    }
    return remainder.trim();
}
```

Use the Class();