# Hive remove multiple space between the string

Tags: hadoop, hive

In Hive how can I replace multiple spaces between a strings ?

`select regexp_replace('foot    ball','  ',' ')`

Expected output is a string with only one space between them

`foot ball`

Any help is appreciated

Comment: You should use a regex that captures multiple spaces? https://stackoverflow.com/q/2932392/2308683

Comment: Thanks @cricket_007, select regexp_replace('foot    ball',' +',' ')  did the trick for me